# Do phrases like “a bunch of simples arranged chair-wise” advance our understanding of ontology?

Tags: ontology

In the popular YouTube video “[Do Chairs Exist?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXW-QjBsruE)”, the presenter eventually advances the idea that chairs do not exist, but that what we think as a chair is “a bunch of simples arranged chair-wise.”

My question is whether this really advances our understanding of ontology. It seems to me that all of the tricky questions we asked about whether chairs exist, can now be asked of the predicate “arranged chair-wise,” and so all of the problems remain. I'm still not sure how many things can (or should) go in the slot “arranged ____-wise.” I'm still not sure when some specific collections of simples stops being “arranged Ship-of-Thesus-wise” and when another collection of simples begin being “arranged Ship-of-Thesus-wise.” (And for that matter I'm not sure whether that last example shouldn't be “arranged ship-wise”, with the question of whether particular objects can be identified at all being handled separately.)

A question that feels related is whether it is the case that talking about “a bunch of simples arranged chair-wise” implies that “chair-wise” is necessarily (only) a linguistic/cultural construct, or whether it might be taken as a Platonic form.

Comment: Maybe useful Kit Fine, [The Question of Ontology](https://philpapers.org/archive/FINTQO-2.pdf) and [Logic and Ontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/): **Different conceptions of ontology** As a first approximation, ontology is the study of what there is. Many classical philosophical problems are problems in ontology: the question whether or not there is a god, or the problem of the existence of universals, etc.. 1/2

Comment: These are all problems in ontology in the sense that they deal with whether or not a certain thing, or more broadly entity, exists. 2/2

Comment: Having said that: "do chairs exist?" is fine and is a correctly stated question (whose answer is obvious).

Comment: This is a caricature of [mereological nihilism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/material-constitution/#Eli), associated with Unger and van Inwagen. In the original there were "*simples arranged tablewise*". It is a developed position in ontology that answers all questions about existence of not only tables but all composites. In the negative. And those questions do not transfer to the predicates either, those are pragmatic labels and not ontology's concern. On the utility of the paraphrase see van Inwagen's book referenced under the link. Of course, nihilism has its own problems.